# How come setting the background color of a p element also sets the background color for the image above

Tags: html, css

so I'm creating a gallery of images with captions and I'm confused as before I've never had it happen but now when I set the background color of the p element it sets the background behind the element too. I've tried several things so far such as setting the background color of the image to none and other things, but nothing has worked, any help would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code snippet, I will gladly update any more information needed.

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">

    <ul id="products">
        <li><a href="ambco.html"><img src="img/650a.jpg" alt=""><p>Hello I am Jacob 
        and I'm confused as hell and this doesn't make sense...</p></a></li>
        <li><p>Hello I am Jacob and I'm confused as hell and this doesn't
        make sense...</p></li>
        <li><p>Hello I am Jacob and I'm confused as hell and this doesn't
        make sense...</p></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#products {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#products li {
    width: 95%;
    margin: 2.5%;
    float: left;
}

#products img {
    margin-bottom: 15px;
}

#products p {
    background-color: black;
    color: brown;
}

#products a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you reproduce with jsfiddle ? I don't have the same ouput with your code : https://jsfiddle.net/hsmb1pqz/

Comment: You posted my own link, you need to click on the edit button, top left

Comment: Yeah I'm stupid :/ https://jsfiddle.net/boo89100/xx0eq2t6/

Comment: I removed all the `float: left`, are you trying to align the image on the left ? https://jsfiddle.net/hsmb1pqz/5/

Comment: I discovered that it was due to a float left that was some ways higher up on the page and that was the problem! Thank you for making me think about the floating.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have `float: left;` for the `<li>` everything after the `<li>` is collapsing - try switching for `display: inline-block;` on the `<li>` elements, this might work.